# Insert space in between each letter in string

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I try to write a code in batch for inserting space in between each letter of the string.
It may convert `John` to `J o h n` for example.

```
set "string=John"
set string_list=%string:= %
echo %string_list%
```

But I don't know how to indicate this nothing between letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sub-string replacement with an empty search string like `%STRING:= %` does not work.

A nice method to insert <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> after every character is to use `cmd /U` to convert the string to Unicode, that is, to insert a zero-byte after every character, together with `find`, which takes these zero-bytes as line-breaks, so it returns every single character in a separate line; finally, a `for /F` loop captures these lines and accumulates them in a variable, using the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> as a separator:

```cmd
set "STRING=John"
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ('cmd /U /C echo^(%STRING%^| find /V ""') do (
    call set "STRING_LIST=%%STRING_LIST%%%%L "
)
echo(%STRING_LIST:~,-1%
```

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "string=John"
:seploop
set "string_list=%string:~-1% %string_list%" 
set "string=%string:~0,-1%"
if defined string goto seploop
set "string_list=%string_list:~0,-1%"
echo %string_list%
GOTO :EOF
```

Within the loop,string the last character of `string` with <kbd>Space</kbd> and the accumulated list, then remove the last character of `string` until it is empty, then remove the last character from the list as the very first iteration of the loop will add a superfluous <kbd>Space</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You could use [JREPL.BAT - a regular expression text processing utility for the command line](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). JREPL is pure script (hybrid batch/JScript) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party exe file required.

If you want the string to include a leading and trailing space, then:

```
jrepl "" " " /m /s string /rtn string
```

If you only want spaces between existing characters (no leading/trailing spaces), then:

```
jrepl ".(?=.)" "$& " /m /s string /rtn string
```

Since JREPL is itself a batch file, you must use CALL JREPL if you put the command within another script.